# Form submission inside ajax

Tags: ajax, web2py

In my application on a button onClick, I am loading a form in an overlay using ajax. But this for submission is not redirecting to the required page.

I have tried the same form element without ajax and overlay, then it is working fine. So there is no problem with the form element. I think I am missing some settings to invoke form submission inside ajax.

I am using Web2py application.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT:
I have one more similar question. I am displaying a web2py SQLFORM for a db-table in an overlay using ajax. The form submission and data update is working fine. But after the form submit I want to close the overlay and reload the page. Right now, it is showing 'Server Error' inside the overlay. I am using LOAD() to load the form on overlay.

Comment: Once submitted, do you want the entire page to reload with the redirect URL, or do you want the redirect to load within the overlay? If the latter, you'll have to catch the form submission and submit it via Ajax. This is handled automatically if you load the form via web2py's `web2py_component()` Javascript function. It would help if you could show your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the ajax to to catch the form submission and submit. It is working fine. I have one more question. I have edited my question.

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you show your code.